# Typescript missing typedefinition of extended interface

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js, apollo

I'm creating a nuxt project with the @nuxtjs/apollo package and typescript. I want to add the configuration of apollo to my nuxt.config.ts, but it doesn't show all available properties.

The configuration should be able have these options, but it sais: "'wsEndpoint' does not exist in type 'ApolloClientConfig'" :

```ts
import { Configuration } from '@nuxt/types';

const configuration: Configuration = {
  apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: process.env.VUE_APP_ALERTS_COMMENTS_API_HTTP_URL,
        wsEndpoint: process.env.VUE_APP_ALERTS_COMMENTS_API_WS_URL,
        websocketsOnly: false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "esnext.asynciterable",
      "dom"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxtjs/apollo/types/nuxt.d.ts",
      "vue-cli-plugin-apollo",
      "@types/jest",
      "vue-toasted/types",
      "vue-i18n/types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "e2e",
    "./env.config.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "custom.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I did some research on the types:

1. vue-cli-plugin-apollo contains the types which are missing
2. I had to import "@nuxtjs/apollo/types/nuxt.d.ts" and not its index.d.ts because otherwise I had no types for apollo at all (even though the index.d.ts imports nuxt.d.ts)
3. nuxt.d.ts has an interface "ApolloClientConfig" which extends the interface "ApolloClientClientConfig" from "vue-cli-plugin-apollo" package. Autocomplete works for the properties of "ApolloClientConfig" but the ones from "ApolloClientClientConfig" are missing.

I also tried replacing "vue-cli-plugin-apollo" in the tsconfig.json with: "vue-cli-plugin-apollo/types.d.ts" with no difference in the result.

Here is the [nuxt.d.ts](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/blob/master/types/nuxt.d.ts) and the [types.d.ts from "vue-cli-plugin-apollo"](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-apollo/blob/master/types.d.ts).

Here is the relevant part of my package.json

```json
{
...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@nuxtjs/apollo": "^4.0.0-rc19",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "vue-cli-plugin-apollo": "^0.21.3",
    ...
  },
...
}
```

Comment: We ran into some similar issues with things like `csurf` in TypeScript middlewares. It seemed for whatever reason the additional methods or types weren't being properly appended to requests. For things that this, we just opted for JavaScript implementations since they still worked. I don't want to suggest you just use the normal `nuxt.config.js`, but sometimes there are just bigger fish to fry and you gotta move on.

Comment: Agreed, I'm currently working with a separate file for the apollo client which has the type:
`ApolloClientConfig & ApolloClientClientConfig`

Nevertheless this seems to be a very strange problem to me.